# Setting state using useEffect through functions

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I know that you get an error if you use useEffect inside a function. But if I want to update a state variable inside a function or after some conditions have been met, and simeoultaneously update the DOM or its value that is seen on the DOM. What is the best way to do so?

Example code:

```
    const handleClick = () => {

    const newDiff = (Date.now() - startTime);
    console.log('newDiff: ' + newDiff)

    setDiff(newDiff);
    console.log('diff: ' + diff)
    
    setDiffArray(oldArray => [...oldArray, newDiff]);
    console.log("diffArray: " + diffArray)

    if (newDiff !== undefined) {
    if (diffArray !== undefined && diffArray.length >= 5){
      gameReset();
    }
    console.log(diffArray);
  }
    setStartTime(Date.now());
    respawn();
    console.log(diffArray);
  }
```

To give you some context, `newDiff` gets generated after clicking on a div, immediately after it is set to state using `setDiffArray`, I attempt to render it to a `<div>` after all computations are done, but the state is still lagging a render behind and therefore the last div is not recorded and saved to the array.

If I try to use useEffect, I get an error that I can't use it inside of a function.

Comment: You can move `setDiffArray` and the rest of the code below to a useEffect with `diff` as a dependency.

Comment: I tried that once before but it didn't work as intended, gonna try again.

Comment: apparently my issue is that my state is not updating after the first click. I'm open for ideas